# Deleting your own closed questions fails silently on the mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, deleted-questions, usability

There is some sort of delay for deletion of your own closed questions (2 days, I think) for non-mods. Now, when you try deleting a closed question on the desktop site, it nicely tells you "please wait xyz to allow for possible reopening" (in a box similar to the "please consider adding a comment explaining why you downvoted" thingy).

On mobile, it just reloads the page—there is no indicator that deletion is not allowed.

Either completely disable the delete button on mobile for closed questions, or give it a popup as well. Not letting the user know what's wrong is confusing.